# Depreciated HttpGet in 5.1 is not working on 6.0

Tags: android, post, get, deprecated

Some deprecated method, package related to HTTP Get & Post methods are removed in Android 6.0. Is there any alternative solution available?

My current code is:

```
//these are all depriciated in 5.0 & removed in 6.0
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpRequest;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.entity.EntityTemplate;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

Please help me find a solution.
Also please specify modified deprecated methods in 6.0.

Answer (score 3):

Android HttpClient [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.1.html#http) since API version 22. You should use alternative methods for connectivity.

For example:

1. [HttpUrlConnection](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html)
2. [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)
3. [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)

Comment: sir, please help me to apply "OkHttp" or HttpUrlConnection" to my code mentioned above. (my code is related to Server side)

Comment: @JeevanBM unfortunately it will be better if you do it your self, since it will be hard to just edit the code without compile.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [URLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) class.

Comment: My project related to client - server connection. For client side I used "Admin, Doctor, Patient". Here I used URLConnection to deprecation. I'm asking for server side.

Comment: If I can use URLConnection, then please help me to respond i.e HttpResponse in URLConnection.

Comment: I searched in internet, I'm getting only URLConnection as answer. Please let me know if any other solution.